# Как передвинуть объект на определённое расстояние в направлении курсора мыши в Unity 2D?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Хочу сделать рывок в Unity 2D, будто бы в игре Celeste, где рывок обнуляет ускорение игрока и игнорирует гравитацию. Я полагаю, что он реализован через некое "Передвижение" героя в направление рывка. Как найти вектор от игрока до курсора я уже знаю и понимаю, поэтому хотел бы узнать ответ на остальную часть вопроса. В данный момент рывок представляет из себя следующее:

```
void Dash(){
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rb.AddForce(mouseDir * DashForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Но к сожалению, он не работает так, как я описал выше, буду признателен за любую помощь, спасибо заранее!